# ts-jest providing different instances of a mock the test and the module

Tags: mocking, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using an automatic mock of a file that exports a function, actual file looks like

```
export const serialize = (type:boolean) => (data) => {....}
```

In the debugger I can see that in the module (controller) I'm testing, that `serialize` is called and is a mock.

in my test, I have

```
import {controller} from '../../src/controller'
import {serialize} from '../../src/serialize'
jest.mock('../../src/serialize');

describe('test', () => {
    it('serialize'), (done) => { 
       controller.put();  //<-- calls serialize
       expect(serialize).toHaveBeenCalled();  // <-- this fails, with 0 calls
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in the Controller, the serialize function was called in a way that caused the mockConfig in jest which is stored in a WeakMap, to be removed from the weak map. Hence I moved the call so the GC did collect the reference.